# JavaScript Autofill - Form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to start a form base HTML page.

My goal of this is to have the second inbox autofill based on the user input for the first input. I've looked at guides and this is the script I've wrote but it's not working. I was working what's wrong with it.

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#Dnumber").keyup(function(){
    update();
 });

 function update() {
 $("#Dnumber1").val($('#Dnumber').val());
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="input1">
District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber" name="Dnumber"/> <br>
</div>

<div class="input1">
District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber1" name="Dnumber1"/> <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

User can change `#Dnumber` `.value` using arrows, use `input` event.

```html
<div class="input1">
  District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber" name="Dnumber" /> <br>
</div>

<div class="input1">
  District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber1" name="Dnumber1" /> <br>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dn = $("#Dnumber"),
    dn1 = $("#Dnumber1");
  dn.on("input", function() {
    update();
  });

  function update() {
    dn1.val(dn.val());
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had script tags in the js part of the snippet

```js
$("#Dnumber").keyup(function() {
  update();
});

function update() {
  $("#Dnumber1").val($('#Dnumber').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input1">
  District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber" name="Dnumber" /> <br>
</div>

<div class="input1">
  District Number: &nbsp; <input type="number" id="Dnumber1" name="Dnumber1" /> <br>
</div>
```